# Gzip writer not writing gzip data to S3 in Golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I've got a (hopefully) simple problem. I'm trying to write the results of a HTTP request to a Gzip file in S3. However when downloading the resultant file from S3, it's just in plain text and not compressed. Below is a snippet of the code (sans bootstrapping). The code builds, lints and runs without error, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
r, w := io.Pipe()
gw := gzip.NewWriter(w)
go func() {
    defer w.Close()
    defer gw.Close()
    _, err := gw.Write(httpResponse)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(“error”)
    }
}()
cfg, _ := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
s3Client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
ul := manager.NewUploader(s3Client)
_, err := ul.Upload(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
    Bucket:          aws.String(bucket),
    ContentEncoding: aws.String("gzip"),
    Key:             aws.String(fileName),
    Body:            r,
})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(“error”)
}
```

Comment: How do you download the file from S3 and how did you determine that the file was not compressed?

Comment: @BaytaDarell downloaded via the S3 GUI. Verified it's not compressed because it opens up directly in a text editor.

Comment: You specified a content encoding of gzip.  Most browsers will respond by decompressing that.  Either don't specify a content encoding, or use something like AWS's CLI that won't decompress the file for you.

Comment: OMFG! Felt like I was on a never ending round-a-bout ride. Can confirm using the CLI to d/l the file confirms the file is gzipped. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

This is a side effect of downloading via the browser, it'll decode the gzip but leave the .gz extension (which is frankly confusing). If you use the AWS cli or API to download the file, it will remain as GZIP.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/940605/chromium-prevent-unpacking-tar-gz?noredirect=1&lq=1